# How much it is important to keep the private key in safe place?

Tags: android, google-play

I bought an app from another developer , we transfer the app to my account following this process https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en .
then I've asked the developer to send me the keystore which contain the private key (alias key).

according to http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html it's not possible to update a new app with different alias key (private key).
and also it's mentioned How much important to keep the private key in secure place !

now there is some one else who has the private key (key alias) , and my app is not secured enough , what should I do ?

Comment: Unless he have access to your developer account, you don't need to be worried

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan thank you for your response but according to the link which i provide above, "that person could sign and distribute apps that maliciously replace your authentic apps or corrupt them. Such a person could also sign and distribute apps under your identity that attack other apps or the system itself, or corrupt or steal user data." !

Comment: Have you bought the app with a standart contract that forbids the former developer to do anything without your notice and agreement?

Comment: @BojanKseneman thank you for your response, yes we have a contract that we wrote together, but that just a contract ! and not some thing  that prevent him technically from malicious the app !

Comment: @david Yes, that person could sign and distribute apps that maliciously replace your authentic app, however he cannot do this through the Google Play Store unless he also has access to your developer account. In order to receive a malicious version of the app a user would need to manually download the app from a third party site, change their device security settings to allow non-Android market apps, and manually install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appId `com.example.appname` along with the keystore signature can identify an app uniquely. Moreover apps of the same signature can share data between them (see doc [`android:sharedUserId`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid)).

Without your private key you cannot update your application anymore!

This does not actually force you not to bring up the "same" app with a different appId and a different signature!

For the users this means that

- they will stop getting updates on the old app (as it is published as a different app)
- will lose any local progress is saved by the app
- will have to manually install the new app

But it could be a way to avoid any unauthorized publications / modifications of your app!

The only thing that could protect you in terms of the previous owner of your app should be the contract that you may have signed during your co-operation or at the end of it. So lawyers will take action in case of any malicious usage of them!

---

If I were you I will try to measure out the 3 drawbacks for the users (see dots above) and how harmful will be for me and my app to be hacked. In case you feel that you are not comfortable to continue with the existing app then you may think to create a "boarding update" to the existing app so the user will move to the new one as smooth as possible :D

Comment: thank you for your answer, can I change the alias key or the app id (package name) ? and How google play accept to publish apps that steal other app data ?

Comment: Changing `app id` means another app. Regarding the alias I have never tried it so I don't know if it can solve your problem in any way. Regarding the "steal other app data" I don't really get your point but if it refer to the "share data between them" I added some extra documentation from android how this is possible. But I want to point that I have never tried to use this feature so I don't know if it is possible programmatically to use it without having access to the one of the two apps.

Comment: but is it possible to upload another application to google play with the same private  key(alias key) ?

Comment: Yes! I have some of them published with the same keystore file and same alias at different google accounts. Not a good idea but it happened. :(

Comment: last question : there are others who are commented on my question, that the developer who has the alias key , can malicious my app just if he has access to the google play developer account , what do you think about that ?

Comment: The point that is made by @Alex Baker is right as you cannot publish a second app with the same appId at play store. But there are dozen of sites that "promise" hacked or unlimited apks just like some original ones, users that do download them are agreed to "non-Android market apps". (I also added a tip to my original post)